# ggplot syntax for data distribution

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, data-visualization, distribution

I'm trying to plot a distribution of the data for the beforeMinWageLaw and afterMinWageLaw variables but when I store it in df instead of seattleData, r says "Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (43): x". How can I fix this? Also, how could I do a normal probability plot to get that view of the data's normality? Thanks.

```
#Import Data
#seattleData <- read.table(file=file.choose(),
#                          header=T, sep=",",)

library(ggplot2)

#Define Variables
 food_drink_workers <- seattleData$food_drink_workers
 MinWage <- seattleData$washington_state_minwage
 afterMinWageLaw <- food_drink_workers[304:346]
 beforeMinWageLaw <- food_drink_workers[1:303]
 df <- data.frame(seattleData)

#Display Data Distribution with ggplot
 x <-ggplot(df, aes(x=food_drink_workers)) + 
  geom_histogram(mapping = aes(y = ..density..), color="black",     fill="white") +
  geom_density(alpha=.2, fill="blue")
  x + geom_vline(xintercept = c(108.8636), linetype = "dashed", color = "red") + 
    ggtitle("Distribtution of the Data") + xlab("Seattle MSA Food and Drink          Workers") + ylab("Density")

#Conduct Two Sample t-test
 options(scipen = 100)
 tTest <- t.test(beforeMinWageLaw, afterMinWageLaw, mu=0, alternative = "less",
                conf=.95, var.equal = F, paired = F)
```

You can download the data here: https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/SMU53426607072200001SA

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRTDf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error message "Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (43): x" because vector `afterMinWageLaw` has a length of 43 values and `beforeMinWageLaw` has a length of 303 values, and this is why you cannot reference them within the same aesthetics `aes()`, I guess.

I would use different visualizations in one plot, so that you can set different aesthetics also with a different length or row count of your data. At first, I would split your data into two data frames, one for before the law and another one for after the law. Using ggplot, you can reference different data frames in one plot, in your case for example like this:

```
#set row indicex ranges for before and after law
row_index_range_before <- 1:303;
row_index_range_after <- 304:346;

#define two data frames
df_before <- data.frame(seattleData)[row_index_range_before, ];
df_after <- data.frame(seattleData)[row_index_range_after, ];

#display data distributions of both data frames with ggplot
x <- ggplot() + 
  geom_histogram(
    data = df_before
    ,mapping = aes(
      x = food_drink_workers
      ,y = ..density..
      ,color = "blue")
    ,fill = "white") +
  geom_histogram(
    data = df_after
    ,mapping = aes(
      x = food_drink_workers
      ,y = ..density..
      ,color = "red")
    ,fill = "white") +
  geom_density(
    data = df_before
    ,mapping = aes(
      x = food_drink_workers
      ,y = ..density..
      ,fill = "blue")
    ,alpha = .2) +
  geom_density(
    data = df_after
    ,mapping = aes(
      x = food_drink_workers
      ,y = ..density..
      ,fill = "red")
    ,alpha = .2) +
  scale_colour_manual(
    name = "Color"
    ,values = c("blue" = "blue", "red" = "red")
    ,labels = c("blue" = "Before Law", "red" = "After Law")) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    name = "Fill"
    ,values = c("blue" = "blue", "red" = "red")
    ,labels = c("blue" = "Before Law","red" = "After Law"));

x + geom_vline(
  xintercept = c(108.8636)
  ,linetype = "dashed"
  ,color = "red") + 
ggtitle("Distribtution of the Data") + 
  xlab("Seattle MSA Food and Drink          Workers") + 
  ylab("Density");
```

But this way, you could also reference `afterMinWageLaw` and `beforeMinWageLaw` as `x` in `aes()` and remove `data` referencing the data frame, I think.

To also plot the legend you need to set `color` or `fill` within `aes()` and add `scale_colour_manual()` or `scale_fill_manual()` to your plot.[image]

Comment: Wow, this is awesome. Thank you so much. Is it possible to add a legend for this?

Comment: Can you also explain the semicolon (;) in your code? I'm still pretty new to r.

Comment: Using the semicolon is optional. I updated the R-code so that legends are added.

Comment: Thank you so much.